# How to get the offsetParent() which is relative only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

I have searched this one a bit now. Is there a way to get only the `offsetParent()` of an element where that parent is positioned **relative** only? I don't want other parents with all positions. Just the parent that has relative position.

I was thinking of something like

```
$('myelement').offsetParent().css('position','relative');
```

I want it to return only the first positioned parent that has relative position but this won't solve it, I know.

Comment: you would have to get all parents and then search through each parent's styles to see if their position is set to relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution in practice: http://jsfiddle.net/tYQPy/

Assuming you want the parent closest to the child container, all you need is a little recursion. =)

```
function findOffsetParent(target) {
    var parent = target.offsetParent();

    if (parent.css('position') === 'relative') {
        return parent;
    }
    else {
        return findOffsetParent(parent);
    }
}
```

Feed the parameter to that function a jQuery selected element, and it will return to you the jQuery selection of the relative positioned parent.

**Note**, that this will be very cumbersome if you need to iterate through a lot of elements.

Written with jQuery seeing that you have jQuery in your initial question

Comment: This works out really good, just recursive until you find the relative parent. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What about a loop?

```
function findRelative(selector) {
   for(var $e = $('selector'); $e.css('position') !== 'relative'; $e = $e.offsetParent()) {
      if($e.length === 0) return null;
   }
   return $e;
}
```